# How can I organize roles in subdirectories in ansible

Tags: ansible

How can I organize roles in subdirectories in ansible? I have searched for an answer to this question and seen some people people say it's possible. But I can’t find an example of how to use multiple directories from which ansible will use roles.

How can I organize roles in subdirectories in ansible so that I could for example have the structure "roles/server/nginx" and "roles/devpc/linuxlaptop" pcrather than "roles/nginx" and "roles/devpc/linuxlaptop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your roles are generic enough to be used in different projects (which I recommend) you should keep it outside your project's root folder.
Import them to your projects through your `main.yml` file and play around with the variables through the `vars/main.ym`l file.

If the roles are indeed project specific, then go ahead and create a `roles` folder in your project folder and start creating new ones:

```
ansible-galaxy init test-role-1
```

or import other roles such as from [geerlingguy](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-for-devops)

Make sure you keep them as generic as possible. If you wish to run against different targets, make use of the variables or conditionals. Better keeping a single role working than X others...

Comment: You can go a step further by placing roles in collections. You have an artifact recognized by ansible that you can call in your requirements.yml. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/playbooks_roles.html#id10 thanks! this is how you would import an external role, it seems like

Comment: Correct! That is the way